# bisect.insort for list of lists in python 3.9.1

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.9.1  and trying to understand the bisect in 2d array.

I have a list of list like below and trying to insert a value to it using bisect.insort,
but nothing works.

How to make it work?

```
l = [[[-1, 0], [0, 5], [3, 5]],
     [[-1, 0], [2, 6]],
     [[-1, 0], [1, 10]]]

l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

bisect.insort(l, 4)             # 1
bisect.insort(l, [4])           # 2
bisect.insort(l, [4,1])         # 3
print(f"l ={l}")
```

all three #1 - #3 are throwing TypeError.

How to insert a list to the list of lists by using insort in ?

Answer (score 1):

You stopped one version too soon:

```
bisect.insort(l, [[4,1]])
```

Which may *not* produce what you want, but you never made clear exactly what that was.  (And `l` is a list of lists *of lists*.)

Comment: thanks for pointing out. right it's a list of lists of lists.